# MethodInfo.Invoke() suppresses Exception

Tags: c#, reflection

Im using reflection to invoke a method which throws a exception. 
But this exception is not thrown, neigter i can catch it.
Im invoking by calling:

```cs
GetMethod().Invoke(myInstance, new object[] { result });
```

Where result is of type Object. 
The called method throws a exception like:

```cs
public async Task MyMethod(Object input)
    {
        // do something...
        throw new Exception("Error");

    }
```

If i dont use a try-catch block, the application continuous as well as if i use one like:

```cs
try
{
    GetMethod().Invoke(myInstance, new object[] { result });
    log("everything is ok");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    log(e.message) 
}
```

So the expected output should be:

> Error

but is

> everything is ok

Comment: Check if this applies to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599078/uncatcheable-exception-from-methodinfo-invoke?rq=1

Comment: @josè no, but thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method returns a `Task`, so does not actually throw an exception. In order to get the exception, you should unwrap the task first:

```
var result = GetMethod().Invoke(myInstance, new object[] { result });
if (result is Task task)
{
    // this line will throw.
    await task;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`MyMethod` *doesn't* throw an exception.  It returns a `Task` that will eventually be in a faulted state.  You can access the members of that task (when it has completed) to see that it resulted in an exception, but calling `MyMethod` will *never* throw an exception because it's an `async` method.  It will *only* ever return a `Task` in one state or another.

Answer (score 0):

I faced This issue and I did this which will work 100%,
Try taking the result as dynamic and check for Exception as follows:-

```
dynamic res = GetMethod().Invoke(myInstance, new object[] { result });
            if (res.Exception != null)
            {
                throw res.Exception;
            }
```